# How to add more characters to preg replace array

Tags: php

i am new to php. Can anyone please tell me how to add more characters like comma and double quotes(, ") to this preg_replace array.

```
$filter = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/is', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
/[^a-z0-9,"]/is
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty basic:

```
$filter = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9," ]/is', '', $text);
```

For more information on Regular Expressions check out [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

**EDIT**

Given the comment, added the space character to not be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried this already. But if i have the $text = "My word goes, here" This will output without the space between the words, i just want only remove (,) not space. I will happy if you can give me a solution for this.

Comment: Next time, post that up in the question. Modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regular expression to remove comma and double quote but not space

```
$filter = preg_replace('/[,"]/is', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

.. this can help you ...
http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

and you need

> $new_text = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s]/is', '', $text);